# Search and Extract Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of information. In the first column I have names 1-10. I also have 10 columns named jobs 1-10. I have the data all in between based on the name of the person. For example, if you look at name 3 they have 10 jobs in the same row. My question is, I have created a drop down list with the 10 names below that table. What I want to do is when I click the name from the dropdown list, the row for that name automatically gets populated across the row in the 10 columns. I have tried VLOOKUP but having trouble with the different syntax options. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, the following may help.

Let's suppose your data is set-up like this:

```
      A        B       C       D
1     Name     Job1    Job2    Job3
2     Bob      Washing Vacuum  Ironing
3     Sue      Dust    Polish  Mop
```

Now in cell `A5` I have a drop down list of names i.e. Bob and Sue. When I select a name in A5 I want all their jobs in the same row i.e. cells B5, C5 and D5.

```
B5 =VLOOKUP($A$5, $A$1:$D$3, 2, false)
C5 =VLOOKUP($A$5, $A$1:$D$3, 3, false)
D5 =VLOOKUP($A$5, $A$1:$D$3, 4, false)
```

Does that help? I appreciate you have 10 jobs but you can easily replicate.

Comment: Yes that helped. My problem was I was trying to find a one line formula to get all of the data in the row. I realized about an hour after I posted that I could just do it the example you gave. I appreciate the answer and help.

Comment: If you'd rather go with automatic increments, you can use COLUMN() function making `VLOOKUP($A$5, $A$1:$D$3, COLUMN(), false)` the formula. COLUMN will automatically provide you with 2,3,4 dependeing on column B,C,D and so on.. you can just keep copy pasting, without a need to edit the formula (as long as your columns are consecutive or follow some sort of sequence)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return values into several fields.

VLOOKUP returns a scalar. You need to write a macro.
You can record and then change the things you recorded.